# Need Help Reading JSON object from a URL in a HTML

Tags: html, json

I am trying to create a website in where I can get a particular json object from a url and then display it on the website. The field that I am trying to display is UV_INDEX out of three fields. Nothing is being printed out. I don't even know if it is getting the json object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>EPA </h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};

getJSON('http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVDAILY/ZIP/92507/JSON').then(function(data) {
    document.getElementById('UV_INDEX').innerHtml=json.result;
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + json.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    result.innerText = data.result; //display the result in an HTML element
}, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I added a third-party chrome extenstion for CORS issue. But I get this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: json is not definedmessage: "json is not defined"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: Error
```

Comment: You might be running into CORS issues.

Comment: I would suggest checking your browser's debugging/network console to see what happened to the request.  Looking at the URL in your code, @Scimonster is probably correct that it's a CORS issue since "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this. I don't understand what a CORS issue is.

Comment: AngularJS could be good for this?

Comment: Can you use jQuery?  If so I can make an example that worked for me

Comment: You are running into a CORS related issue.  You cannot use AJAX json to grab the data from the site.  Are you able to use php or any other back side server code like php or asp.net etc?

Comment: I have not restricted my any language.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [Ajax plugin](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/) to make CORS request where the CORS headers are not being served from service.

Add Jquery library and add your installed CORS ajax scripts after that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can make cross origin request by just adding **crossOrigin: true** in your Ajax:
E.g.

```
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: "http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVDAILY/ZIP/92507/JSON/",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);    
    }
});
```

You can try putting the same URL in the below demo page to receive the Json data.
See [live demo](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/examples/cross-origin.htm).

Comment: so the console print should just print out the entire json object right?

Comment: What is your server side technology e.g. php/asp.net etc.?

Comment: This code will result in a cors denied error.  It will never return successful.  From what I could find, you will need to implement jsonp with the ajax request or use a server side technology like php etc.